# Query is giving me a boolean false error

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need help! I have been already 3 days with the same problem. I know that the query is not giving me a boolean true result. I dont even know what it is giving me. The problem it gives me is :

> Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 2 to be string, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\caf\pages\log.php on line 48

I already tried converting the result into string, but I have seen that the problem is in the output given to me on this line:

```
$query_pages_result = mysqli_query($connection, $get_pages_query)  or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

So please someone help me to see if this line can give me the result I want, which is to see how many pages I have in the tables record. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

session_start();

// GET PAGES RECORD FROM LOG TABLE: *********| Only the first time though:
if (isset($_SESSION['log']) != 'logging')
{
    //  Here, just creating a string:
    $pages_record = '';
    $insert_query = '';
    //      Get saved pages from the database:
    $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-1 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

    //      Query string to pull all pages from table record:
    $get_pages_query = "select *  from `log-page` order by `log-id`";

    //      Query the database, and save result:
    $query_pages_result = mysqli_query($connection, $get_pages_query)  or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    //      Check number of results returned:
    $num_of_results = '';

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_pages_result)) {
    $num_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);

    if ($num_of_results > 0)
    {
        // Loop through the result array: Each time, one row, and then the next one ...
        for ($row = 0; $row < $num_of_results; $row++ )
        {
            // Getting one row:
            $get_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_pages_result);
            // Extracting just the page name from the row:
            $one_page = substr($get_row["page"],strripos($get_row["page"],"/") + 1);
            // Adding this page name to the string created previously:
            if ($row == 0)
            {
                $pages_record .= $one_page;
            }
            else 
            {
                $pages_record .= ",".$one_page;
            }           
        }

        // Once all pages have been read and saved to the string
        // now we save it to the session:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = $pages_record;
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'logging'; // This just tells us, we are logging pages to the database.
    }
    else 
    {
        // There are no pages in the table:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = "";
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'logging'; // This just tells us, we are logging pages to the database.
    }
}

// Check if page is already in session list.
$pages_array = array();
if (strlen(isset($_SESSION['logpages'])) > 0 )
{
    // string variable that holds all pages separated by commas:
    $pages_string =  $_SESSION['logpages'];

    // creating an Array to hold all pages already logged in server:
    if (strstr($pages_string, ","))
    {
        $pages_array = explode(",", $pages_string);
    }
    else // just means there's only one page in the record
    {
        // so, we push it inside the array.
        array_push($pages_array, $pages_string);
    }

    // current page: [ We are extracting only the page, not the entire url, Exmp: login.php ]
    $current_page = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/") + 1);

    // Check if current_page is in the array already:
    if (!in_array($current_page, $pages_array))
    {
        // IF is NOT in the array, then add it:
        array_push($pages_array, $current_page);

        // Add it to the Session variable too:
        $pages_string = implode(",", $pages_array);

        // Re-save it to SESSION:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = $pages_string;

        // Now, add it to the database table "log-page""
        $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Unable to connect!");
        mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

        // Query to insert page description into the table:
        // [ date - time - page - user ]
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `log-page` 
            (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`) VALUES 
            ('".date("Y-m-d")."', '".date("H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."', '".(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_UNAME']))."')"; 
            mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

        // INSERTING INTO DATABASE TABLE:
        mysqli_query($connection, $insert_query) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-2 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error($connection));
        // Done!
    }
    else 
    {
        // IF it IS in the list, just SKIP.
    }
}
else 
{
    // means, that there are absolutely no pages saved in the database, basically this is the first log:
    $_SESSION['logpages'] = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/") + 1);    

    // Now, add it to the database table "log-page""
    $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Unable to connect!");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

    // Query to insert page description into the table:
    // [ date - time - page - user ]
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO `log-page` 
        (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`) VALUES 
        ('".date("Y-m-d")."', '".date("H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."', '".(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_UNAME']))."')"; 
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');
    // INSERTING INTO DATABASE TABLE:
    mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-2 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error($connection));
    // Done!    
}

}?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but does `mysql_error` go with `mysqli_query`?

Comment: Actually, the issue is more likely here: `if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_pages_result))`, as you're passing a result object into mysqli_prepare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_pages_result)) {
```

The second variable to [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) needs to be the actual SQL query, not the result-object of executing the query with `mysqli_query`. You may have your logic backwards with this. You're *supposed* to prepare the statement and *then* execute it. It looks like you're executing it, and then trying to prepare it.

Try to remove the `$query_pages_result = mysqli_query(...` line and change the rest to:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $get_pages_query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
```

However, your query doesn't have any binding parameters, so you may actually be able to just use `mysqli_query` and drop the `mysqli_prepare` in this situation - your preference really.

Comment: Thanks, the error is no longer running. Now I have other problems like when I click on the log in, it sends me back to the login page, I dont know if that is part of this script or not. If it is not, then ignore the comment.

Comment: @jjumar Sorry, but there is no redirection code in the sample-code from your question - can't help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is in the line indicated

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query_pages_result))
```

$query_pages_result is  not a string, its the result handle for the query you already ran, you dont need to prepare it, so this code isnt needed, you already got the query and the count of lines, just now step through it.

Comment: Thanks, the error is no longer running. Now I have other problems like when I click on the log in, it sends me back to the login page, I dont know if that is part of this script or not. If it is not, then ignore the comment.